# Chrome devtools audits tab does not show

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, audit

My version of google chrome is **83.0.4103.116 (Build oficial) (64 bits) (cohort: Stable)**

But **audits tab** does not show on devtools.

[image: DevTools without audit option]

Any idea of how enable audit tab?

Comment: It's renamed to `Lighthouse` now because that was its real name all along.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The Audits tab does *not* exist anymore, it has been replaced with Lighthouse (See [What's new in DevTools (Chrome 83)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/03/devtools#lighthouse)).

Just use Lighthouse.

Answer (score 0):

the Audits panel is now the **Lighthouse** panel.

Answer (score 0):

`(for Windows)`

> Ctrl+Shift+P -> **Lighthouse**